# Java Script is not redirecting using window.location

Tags: php, javascript

I am calling the js function from the href

```
function topicApproval()
{
 var approve = confirm('Do you wish to proceed?');
 if(approve)
 {
 window.location('http://www.sample.com');
 }
}
```

Here is the function called Yes

But it is not redirecting........
Please help me..

Comment: Does Firebug console mention any errors?

Answer (score 5):

Use:

```
window.location = 'http://sample.com';
```

[More info](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.location)

Answer (score 4):

You cal also use

```
window.location = 'http://sample.com';
window.location.href="http://www.example.com/";  and
window.location.replace('example.html');
```

for more details [here](http://andylangton.co.uk/articles/javascript/javascript-redirect-scripts/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer.It works when I put one alert message like window.location.replace('http://www.sample.com/');
alert("HI"); Why this happens due to time delay or something help.................

Answer (score 1):

Why not using `document.location.href = 'http://location.com'` which is supported by every browser.