# How to open new page in javascript without clicking a link

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have read through a number of posts on this and tried different approaches but am still having trouble.  I have an html form in a php page which has an onClick command to run a javascript validation procedure when the user clicks a button on the screen. This all works fine, but at the end of the validation I want to open a new php page **in the same tab** based on the value of a customURL variable (which does contain the correct URL). But the page will only reload itself,not the new page. I have tried window.location.href, location.href and document.location. Does anyone have any ideas why none of these work, or can suggest an alternative approach?  Thank you.

```
if(optionChosen == "overview") { customURL ='overview.php'; }
if(optionChosen == "tasks")    { customURL ='tasks.php';}
if(optionChosen == "guidance") { customURL ='guidance.php';}
if(optionChosen == "feedback") { customURL ='feedback.php';}
if(optionChosen == "progress") { customURL ='progress.php';}

customURL = customURL + "?uid=" + unitChosen;
document.location = customURL;
```

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7077770/window-location-href-and-window-open-methods-in-javascript

Comment: You have to use `window.open(customURL,'_blank');` instead of `document.location = customURL;`

Comment: `window.location.href = customURL` should work. If it isn't, open up the browser console and see if anything is being printed out

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java Script is not redirecting using window.location](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7887196/java-script-is-not-redirecting-using-window-location)

Comment: Thanks guys - but no luck.  window.open at least opens the new page, but in a new tab which I don't want - it has to be in the existing tab.  window.location and window.location.href just seems to reloas the existing page in the same tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all - found a new approach in the end which is working for me - using
    document.input.action = customURL;
and returning to the input form.
So will stick with this.  Appreciate your suggestions and help.

Answer (score 3):

First make sure that anyone of the options is selected or write the code like this

```
if(optionChosen == "overview") { customURL ='overview.php'; }
else if(optionChosen == "tasks")    { customURL ='tasks.php';}
else if(optionChosen == "guidance") { customURL ='guidance.php';}
else if(optionChosen == "feedback") { customURL ='feedback.php';}
else { customURL ='progress.php';}
```

---

**Use this to avoid redirects when a user clicks "back" in their browser**

```
window.location.replace('http://somewhereelse.com');
```

---

**Use this to redirect, a back button call will trigger the redirection again**

```
window.location.href = "http://somewhereelse.com";
```

---

### Then use any of this following method as per your requirements.

---

**Given for completeness, essentially an alias to window.location.href**

```
window.location = "http://somewhereelse.com";
```

Comment: thanks AaJey I will amend this, although it is not what is at fault here as I have checked that the correct URL is being placed in the customURL variable.  Just need to find a way of displaying the new page in the same tab - no luck yet depsite the suggestions made,

Answer (score 2):

do `window.location.href = customURL;`

Comment: @nl-x  A comment alone would have sufficed

Comment: @nl-x yes it is and it also proves how poor the question is. A simple Google search would have given him the correct syntax.

Comment: Thanks I am aware of the syntax.. window.location /window.location.href / window.location.replace / document.location / all reload the same page in the tab. window.open opens the new page but in a new tab. I can't work out why this is the case.

Answer (score 1):

it is `window.location` , not `document.location` , and to be more precise it's actually `window.location.href`